# How to submit an Instagram app for review without a company

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

How do I submit my Instagram app for review if I don't have a company? Can I write any name there or do I need an actual company? I'm also wondering if I need an actual domain or is it ok if I submit a Heroku link?

Sorry for asking these questions here, but I have no idea where else to ask these kind of questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a Company. Just write the name of your website / App. It implies you are **DBA** ([Doing-business-as](http://www.bizfilings.com/learn/file-dba.aspx)).

The ***bigger*** thing you need to worry about -- or structure properly in order to get approved is -- presenting a valid use-case so they don't reject your app.

Every since Facebook (instagram app purchaser) changed the API TOS on **November 17th, 2015**, lots of **App Developers using the Instagram API are getting rejected left and right**.

[image]

They also "sand-boxed" the API Client to use useless test accounts.

#### Recommended Reading

1. [Instagram API Limits Valid Use Cases](http://www.carsonshold.com/2015/12/instagram-api-limits-valid-use-cases/) [Facebook Instagram Levies
   Strict API Restrictions For Third-Party Apps](http://www.bidnessetc.com/57748-facebook-instagram-levies-strict-api-restrictions-for-thirdparty-apps/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the additional links! I've read the TOS before and am aware of their strict limitations. In my opinion I'm not doing anything that's against their TOS so I hope they approve my app. Do you happen to know if I need an actual domain or can I simply give a link to myAppName.herokuapp.com and change it later when I purchase an actual domain for my project?

Comment: A "normal" company would not reject your `myAppName.herokuapp.com` app url, but Facebook is anything but normal ;) I personally would register a domain and point the app to that cos I think having your URL as an actual domain name gives it more credibility and reduces the chances of getting rejected by the uberlord that we know as Facebook.